# ¿Como hacer click sobre un button que esta en el header de un collapsible sin que abra o cierre el collapsible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

Cordial saludo, tengo una serie de botones y switch en el header de unos collapsibles, y cada que interactuó con ellos, el collpasible se abre o se cierra, dependiendo el caso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo evitar que se abran al hacer click en el switch?

Mi codigo:

```
<div class="section receta" id="receta-1" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto">
                    <ul class="collapsible">
                        <li>
                            @* ---- HEADER RECETA 2 ---- *@
                            <div class="collapsible-header" style="color: black; align-items: center;">

                                <label>No</label>                                
                                @* ---- SWITCH AL QUE QUIERO HACER CLICK SIN QUE SE ABRA EL CONTENIDO ---- *@
                                <div class="switch">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
                                        <span class="lever"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <label>Si</label>
                                <h5 style="margin: auto">Receta</h5>
                            </div>
                            @* ---- BODY COLLAPSIBLE ---- *@
                            <div class="collapsible-body" style="background-color: white">
                                <div class="section row equal-col">
                                    <div class="row" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 90%;">
                                        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                                            <div id="responsive-table" class="card card card-default scrollspy">
                                                <div class="card-content">
                                                    <p class="mb-2">
                                                        CONTENIDO
                                                    </p>                                                        
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para responder tu pregunta sería necesario no solo el código html sino también el CSS y el JS que lo gobierna. No existe en html el elemento collapsible por sí mismo (a menos que lo definas con elementos de tipo `details`). De todos modos parece un planteamiento erróneo desde el punto de vista de usabilidad, ya que en este tipo de elemento el comportamiento esperado es que cualquier click que reciba el elemento que actúa de cabecera (`collapsible-header` en tu caso) actúe de interruptor para abrir/cerrar el elemento.

Comment: Échale un ojo a [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) para que el evento no se propague a los elementos padre del elemento que emitió el evento.